# Zend_Lucene and wilcard operator weirdness

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene, wildcard, zend-search-lucene

A quick summary of my problem, the wildcard operator doesn't seem to return the result I am expecting. I am testing this against some `Keyword` field.

Here come a sample showing the issue

```
include 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$autoloader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);


Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer::setDefault(
    new Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_Utf8_CaseInsensitive());
@mkdir('/tmp/test-lucene');
$index = Zend_Search_Lucene::create('/tmp/test-lucene');
$doc = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Document();
$doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Keyword('path', 'root/1/2/3'));
$doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnStored('contents', 'The lazy fox jump over the dog bla bla bla'));
$index->addDocument($doc);


$doc = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Document();
$doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Keyword('path', 'root/1'));
$doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnStored('contents', 'The lazy fox jump over the dog bla bla bla'));
$index->addDocument($doc);

$doc = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Document();
$doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Keyword('path', 'root/3/2/1'));
$doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnStored('contents', 'The lazy fox jump over the dog bla bla bla'));
$index->addDocument($doc);

$doc = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Document();
$doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Keyword('path', 'root/3/2/2'));
$doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnStored('contents', 'The lazy fox jump over the dog bla bla bla'));
$index->addDocument($doc);

$hits = $index->find('path:root/3/2*');
foreach($hits as $hit){
    $doc = $hit->getDocument();
    echo $doc->getFieldValue('path') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

This will return the whole set of documents instead of the last two like I would expected

output:

```
root/1/2/3
root/1
root/3/2/1
root/3/2/2
```

So here my question why lucene (Zend_Lucene in that case) matches the first documents, I thought `Keyword` fields are not tokenized.

PS: for those who might wants to know why I am running this test. I have an ecommerce website with some database, the category table have some path field. For example a category might have this path '/1/2/3' which means it's category with id 3 and the parent category is index 2 etc ...

The problem is when an user do a full text search and specify a category, ideally I want to return the results from that category but also children categories, so I need a lucene way of doing path LIKE '/1/2%'.

One other possibility would be to merge the results from a SQL query and lucene hits, if possible I would like to avoid this case because it could performs poorly.

If you have any ideas, you are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_Utf8Num_CaseInsensitive and replace the slashes with a character that does not occur in your paths but is a word character to Zend_Search_Lucene. I used german ß.

```
include 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$autoloader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);

Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer::setDefault(
    new Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_Utf8Num_CaseInsensitive());
@mkdir('/tmp/test-lucene');
$index = Zend_Search_Lucene::create('/tmp/test-lucene');

foreach (array('root/1/2/3', 'root/1', 'root/3/2/1', 'root/3/2/2') as $path) {
    $path = str_replace('/', 'ß', $path);
    $doc = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Document();
    $doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Keyword('path', $path));
    $index->addDocument($doc);
}

$hits = $index->find(str_replace('/', 'ß', 'path:root/3/2*'));
foreach($hits as $hit){
    echo str_replace('ß', '/', $hit->getDocument()->getFieldValue('path')) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers it works. I see so lucene was removing the numbers because of the analyzer. After I cannot really explain why replace the / by a word letter change anything, Keyword field shouldn't be tokenized right?

Comment: Keyword fields aren't tokenized, that's true. But the search query is.